# Move markers and redraw path with move Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The below code shows two points in the map and draws the driving path between those points. What I'm trying to achieve is when I move a point, it should move the marker and re-draw the path. How can I do that? I appreciate any hints. Thanks.

```
function mapLocation() {
  var directionsDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var istanbul = new google.maps.LatLng(41.015137, 28.979530);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: istanbul
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(41.01524, 28.975994);
    //var end = new google.maps.LatLng(38.334818, -181.884886);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(41.013232, 28.978676);
    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      } else {
        alert("Directions Request from " + start.toUrlValue(6) + " to " + end.toUrlValue(6) + " failed: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
mapLocation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `draggable` option of the `DirectionsRendererOptions` to `true` and pass it to the `DirectionsRenderer` to allow users to edit the rendered route(s).

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true
});
```

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions).

Comment: One question : How can I detect the distance between the points when I change one point's location? While loading this code helps : `alert(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " meters");` But it does nothing when location of points changes.

Comment: To be more precise, how can I detect the new locations of points? Thanks.

Comment: The [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=fr#DirectionsRenderer) has a `directions_changed` event that *is fired when the rendered directions change, either when a new `DirectionsResult` is set or when the user finishes dragging a change to the directions path.*